# Aws SDk Go V2 Lambda, deadline is 1970-01-1 while local debugging

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda

I have simple lambda code:

```
func handleLambdaEvent(ctxOrg context.Context, request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    orgDL, _ := ctxOrg.Deadline()
    fmt.Println(orgDL)
```

when its deployed to aws and called ( from API Gateway ) I see in logs current timestamp + X seconds, but when I run this locally and use awslambdarpc to call it I see:

> 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC

which causes some problems in other parts of this lambda. Is it possible somehow, using awslambdarpc or maybe some config ( just for local ) to define this deadline value ?

Comment: Maybe create an issue at their GitHub site.

Answer (score 0):

ok looks like original awslambdarpc client is simply missing Deadline value set, so I prepared this default deadline to now()+15 seconds in my fork:

https://github.com/goodsafe-eu/awslambdarpc/commit/b6181a1acc581c12945c7361a3a3e4d5ad5f59c4

and now works fine